# boto3 cloudformation list_stacks() function is not listed all the stacks in cloudformation

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have created a stacks in Cloud formation. When try to get all the stacks through aws cli its working but i tried to get all the stack via boto3 API in python. Here, it didn't collect all the stacks information. few of the stacks information missed. I compared both cli and boto3 api results.

I used below commands to list all the stacks

**CLI**

```
aws cloudformation list-stacks --stack-status-filter CREATE_COMPLETE
```

**boto3 API**

```
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
stacks = client.list_stacks(StackStatusFilter=["CREATE_COMPLETE"])
```

Comment: Do you happen to have many stacks, i.e. > 40?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListStacks` [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListStacks.html) is paginated, i.e. it only returns a fixed result size (1MB) until you need to retrieve the next page of the results. The CLI handles pagination automatically for you - in boto3 you have to implement it yourself.

In boto3 you can use a [paginator like this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Paginator.ListStacks) to get all pages:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client("cloudformation")

paginator = client.get_paginator("list_stacks")

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    StackStatusFilter=["CREATE_COMPLETE"],
)

# This contains stack summaries of all stacks in CREATE_COMPLETE
stack_summaries = [
    response["StackSummaries"] for response in response_iterator
]

# Instead of printing you can do something with the stacks :)
print(f"Found {len(stack_summaries)} stacks in CREATE_COMPLETE")
```